# A php file using sleep() function cannot run simultaneously

Tags: php, sleep

I'm newbie in php. I'm now have a problem with sleep function, that is, I have a simple sleep.php file like this: 
`<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
sleep(5);
?>`

When I hit this file simultaneously in 2 tabs, the first one executes and give this result: 2013-05-04 10:06:24
but the second one has to wait for the first one executes completely then give the result: 2013-05-04 10:06:29

My question is why do they cannot execute simultaneously at the same time? Is this php action or because of web service or something else. I'm running nginx 1.3.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look in php.ini to see if session.auto_start is on. It looks like a session locking issue to me.

Comment: I tried, but that's not correct. The same result. I think this is not php problem, it's about web service problem (nginx). Anyway, thank so much, pal :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a browser behavior. actually , you can not execute them totally simultaneously, and one of them execute earlier. with first execute,your browser opens a session for you, and when other execution receives, the browser sense that, it has the same file name in execution.so it waits until first execution is finished and then start second execution of the same file. if you want to see execution of your `echo` statement in two tabs simultaneously, you can naming them in two different file names and execute them in the same browser, or execute one file in two different browser. in both case , you'll get what you expect.

Comment: You're right about naming them in 2 different file names. I tried and have no doubt about that. In fact, when I tried to open the my sleep.php in 2 different computer, they can run simultaneously. I still wonder if this is a browser behavior or nginx problem. So weird!

Comment: @imnobody , it is browser behavior. actually it is because , cookies enabled in browsers. if you disable cookie, then it execute them totally simultaneously.

Comment: you're right, pal! I tested it using curl command. Thanks so much, Amir!